# Multiple Sql Server instances on same machine - cross query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have 1 SQL server machine having 2 instances [Instance1] and [Instance2]

If I need to execute a cross query joining tables like below

```
[Instance1].[db1].[dbo].[table1] 

joins

[Instance2].[db2].[dbo].[table2]
```

Will there be lot of performance hit in above query compared to if both databases are in same instance?

Please note that both instances are in same machine (server).

Thanks for help!

Comment: I was thinking if you could use Linked Server that might help.

Comment: There will be overhead whether that is going to be substantial is debatable. Measure both scenarios. What would be much more important is separation of the data on disk level. Having the same disks serve the databases is going to bite you hard later.

Comment: Getting data from multiple instances will be slower in most cases. Bottom like you have to test both scenarios in your environment to be sure.